# SELECT command denied to user <userID>@<your ip address> for table <table name>

Tags: mysql, express, mysql2, cleardb

i faced this error while calling the query to the database to the **clearDB** .
it returns the error i specified in the title...
**SELECT command denied to user @ for table**  ......
**i uploaded my clearDB on heruko , i am using the express.js mysql2 npm package**
here's my code

> here's my code

```
const promise = db.promise()
const {
    newPass,
    resetTocken
} = req.body
if (!newPass) return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'newPass is required!' })
if (newPass.length < 6) return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'atleast 6 digit password is required!' })
if (!resetTocken) return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'resetTocken is required!' })
const find_user_query = `
select *
from dotor_app_care.wp_users
where ID=?
`
const update_user_query = `
update wp_users
set user_pass=?
where ID=?
`
//verify tocken 
jwt.verify(resetTocken, process.env.FORGOT_PASSWORD_SECRET, async (error, user) => {
    if (error) return res.status(500).json({ msg: 'access denied!' })
    if (user) {
        console.log('user==>', user)
        const [uR, uF] = await promise.execute(find_user_query, [user.id])
        if (uR.length === 0) return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'no user found!' })
        const encryptedPassword = CryptoJS.MD5(newPass).toString();
        await promise.execute(update_user_query, [encryptedPassword, uR[0].ID])
        return res.status(200).json({ msg: "password updated successfully!" })
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in slecting the **Table**

> I was selecting the database table like this

```
select * from databaseName.tableName;
```

> correct way of selecting the database table deployed on the server is:

```
select * from tableName;
```

> **So try to avoid using the DATABASE NAME while selecting the table OR Making Any other query to your mysql database deployed on the server or localy**